# How do I add objects on selected polygons?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

I am trying to create a primitive pipe and I need to add a small cylinder on each selected polygon (see screenshot) to make rivets. How do I do this ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good reason to use Instancing ([DupliFaces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/duplifaces.html) in old terms)

1. Duplicate selected faces and separate it from base object;
2. Create Cylinder, make it parent of separated faces object and copy location - origins must match each other;

**Updated:**

[image: cylinder to object as instance]

3. In Object properties, on Instancing tab select Faces.

[image: DupliFaces]

As instance for DupiFace Cylinder will not be rendered!

After that you can Make Duplicates Real for next processing.

Comment: Could you please describe step 2  in more detail ?

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason. I select cylinder then selected separated faces of the pipe and do CTRL + P --> Object (Keep transform). But it doesn't create other cylinders like it is shown on your upd screenshot 2. It just connects these objects so now if I move cylinder, faces also move.

Comment: `3. In Object properties, on Instancing tab select Faces.`
have you done this?

Comment: Yes, but this still works wrong. Now it looks like that https://imgur.com/a/S11fyua

Comment: To position duplicates in the right places according step 2 you should copy location (maybe with rotation and scale) from base object to instance. Blender very sensitive about scale - clean or apply it to base object!